# file_get_contents doesn't work in seed file but work in the routes file in laravel 5

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, file-get-contents

I am trying to seed a table in laravel using a JSON output of the old table.

When I tried to `file_get_contents('services.json')` in the seed file, I get an exception that the file does not exist and also I tried using `file_exists('services.json')` and it returned `false` but when I tried it from the routes file, it works perfectly fine and my table seeds. My route looks like so:

```
Route::get('test', function(){
    // return JWTAuth::parseToken()->getPayload()->get('username');

    Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::unguard();

    // \Db::table('service')->truncate();

    $servicesDataFromOldDB = file_get_contents('../database/seeds/services.json');
    $servicesJson = json_decode($servicesDataFromOldDB);
    $services = Illuminate\Support\Collection::make($servicesJson);
    $services->each(function($service){
        App\Service::create([
            'id' => $service->id,
            'name' => $service->title,
            'description' => $service->desc,
            'category' => $service->cat,
            'type' => $service->type,
            'hours' => $service->hours,
            'price' => $service->price,
            'note' => $service->note,
            'devdays' => $service->devdays
        ]);
    });

    Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::reguard();
});
```

I am fetching the same file from the same path and it is able to fetch it but not in the seed file. What am I missing?

**EDIT**

```
dd(file_exists(app_path() . '/database/seeds/services.json'));
```

Even this is returning `false`

And moreover I did a `dd(__DIR__)` in the seed file and it was the right path `/var/www/html/archive/database/seeds`

Comment: Fetch it like this: `file_get_contents(basepath() . '/database/seeds/services.json');`

Comment: PHP can be weird about where the 'current directory' is for relative paths. You should try building an absolute path with something like this: `realpath(__DIR__ . '../database/seeds/services.json')`. `__DIR__` is the path of the directory of the *current file*.

Comment: @samlev: Your solution worked. Yes. The `realpath` thing worked. Answer and I'll accept it. Thank you. I don't know why someone down voted my question tho. It is perfectly valid. Anyway thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `__DIR__` you can get the directory that the *current file* is in, then using `realpath()`, you can get the full, qualified path to the file.

```
realpath(__DIR__ . '../database/seeds/services.json');
```

This means that you can set the path relative to the directory of the file you're working in, and be sure that it will work from anywhere else in the code.